# Implementing the decorator pattern generically in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator

I'm trying to implement the runtime decorator pattern (not to be confused with the other kind of decorator, though they could be used the implementation) generically. For example, in this example, BoomThingDecorator is an actual concrete decorator and ThingDecorator is a convenience base class defined to not have to repeat the forwarding declarations for every decorator for this type. Instead of repeating the forward declarations for every class we want to decorate we can generically create such a base decorator class for any interface. I'm not sure if this is possible since TypeScript interfaces don't exist at runtime.

```js
interface IThing {
    run(): void;
}

class Thing implements IThing {
    run(): void {
        null;
    }
}

abstract class ThingDecorator implements IThing {
    protected base: IThing;

    constructor(base: IThing) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    run(): void {
        return this.base.run();
    }
}

class BoomThingDecorator extends ThingDecorator {
    boom(): number {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

e.g. something like

```
abstract class Decorator<T> {
    protected base: T;
    constructor(base: T) { this.base = base; }
    // something to forward all the methods of base
}

class BoomThingDecorator extends Decorator<IThing> {
    // decorator methods
}
```

Comment: It is true that interfaces don't exist at runtime so you will need to tell the decorator which methods to forward.  Given that limitatoin, does [this](https://tsplay.dev/OwErkN) work for you?  If so, I'll write it up as an answer.  If not, please elaborate on why not so I can address it.

Comment: This seems like it's the closest possible thing and by listing all the methods to be forwarded, the decorator will implement the interface. It'll work, thanks.